# Cannot select a radio button. Exception says that another element obscures it

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Im trying to select a radio button on a simple form, following is the link to the webpage that I have used 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/checkout/

I managed to capture the radio buttons and print the ID's of the radio buttons to the console. 
[image]
[image]

Following is the the error occurs when I try to select the radio button

[image]

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element  is not clickable at point (205.5,740.5) because another element  obscures it

Comment: It is better to paste code than add screenshots, especially if the screenshots don't show the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");              
driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/checkout/");
Thread.sleep(2000);

// Radio 2 select
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[9]/div[2]/label")).click();
   Thread.sleep(2000);

// Radio 3 select
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[9]/div[3]/label")).click();
   Thread.sleep(2000);

// Submit button clicked.
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/button")).click();
   Thread.sleep(2000);

   driver.close();
```

In this example I clicked on the second radio button and then clicked on the third radio button and then finally click on Submit button.

This is working fine.

Comment: Any idea why it is not possible to directly select the option?

Comment: you need to click on the radio button for selection.

Answer (score 0):

The exception which you are getting, below solution may resolve it:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(paymentOptionRadio).click().perform();
```

Try click event by action class, it may work as expected.